Java - org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(sourceFile, destination) is failing to copy file
private void copyFile() {
    try {
        String data = "C:\\Test_data\\My_Folder\\data";
        String destination = "D:\\test\\CC";
        File destDir = new File(destination);
        File source = new File(data);
        File files[] = source.listFiles();
        for (File sourceFile : files) {
            if (sourceFile.getName().equals("testdata.yaml")) {
                if (destDir != null) {
                    FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(sourceFile, destDir);
                    System.out.println("File copied");

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while copying file.......!!!!! ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

I have used FileUtils (org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils) library to copy the file (FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(sourceFile, destDir);) from one location to other
File copy is not working and giving following error.

Error while copying file.......!!!!!
java.io.IOException: Bad pathname         
at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)         
at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:483)         
at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:626)         
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.requireCanonicalPathsNotEquals(FileUtils.java:2601)         
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:842)         
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:783)         
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(FileUtils.java:926)         
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(FileUtils.java:897)         
at com.fileop.reader.App.addDatamapYamlToProjectLocation(App.java:29) 
at com.fileop.reader.App.main(App.java:16) 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) 
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)

What I have checked:
Computer has jdk 11
File copy works fine when used FileInputStream and FileOutputStream
When tried to copy using command prompt using ‘copy’ command it works fine.
User has admin access.
Output directory has read and write access.
I have tried including file exists check for both absolute path and canonical path, both paths exist for both source and destination.
Path size is less than 256 characters.
Note: With same jdk 11 and same code, file copy is working fine in some other computer using FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(sourceFile, destDir);
Computer detais:
• OS: Windows
• System type: 64-bit
• Edition: windows 10 professional workstation
Expectations: File copy should happen without any error using FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(sourceFile, destDir)

Could you please try this in your path:
String data = "C:/Test_data/My_Folder/data";
String destination = "D:/test/CC";
maybe it will work.

Something is not clear. The copyFile method doesn't appear in the stack trace you posted. It looks like this line of the stack trace is your code: com.fileop.reader.App.addDatamapYamlToProjectLocation(App.java:29) Is that correct? If so, then maybe you should post the code of method addDatamapYamlToProjectLocation() from class com.fileop.reader.App ?

What @Abra says. Quite apart from that, your code is odd. That iteration might make sense if you were recursing source directories, but you're not. You're copying one file. So why the loop?

It is very easy to add System.out.println to print the paths and value of xyz.exists() to confirm they are valid, which will give you a better understanding of your issue.

Quite right, and while we're on the subject of validity, if (destDir != null) will always be true and won't tell you anything about validity

@JayKanara changing the file separator to / won't make any difference since new File("C:\\Test_data\\My_Folder\\data").equals(new File("C:/Test_data/My_Folder/data")) is true. Obviously it is simpler to use / though.

I don’t get the point of looping over all files of a directory, just to find out whether one specific file exists. And why use archaic external libraries for something built in to Java for a decade? Path in = Path.of("C:\\Test_data\\My_Folder\\data\\testdata.yaml"), out = Path.of("D:\\test\\CC\\testdata.yaml"); if(Files.exists(in)) Files.copy(in, out); That’s all you need. See Path and Files

Some encryption software was running in the PC and it was blocking FileUtils to copy the file, after disabling encryption file copy is started working
